# Why is MCA so much slower than PCA?

Tags: python, performance, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have a large (50k rows, 2k columns) sparse binary dataset, and thus PCA isn't the best option for dimensionality reduction. I downloaded  [this](https://github.com/esafak/mca/blob/master/docs/usage.rst) mca package, and am running the following code:

```py
import mca
import pandas as pd
data_dummy = mca.dummy(pd.DataFrame(data))
mca_counts = mca.MCA(data_dummy)
mca_components = mca_counts.fs_r(1)
```

I've let it run for over an hour, and still nothing. In comparison, sklearn's PCA implementation churns through the same dataset in under 30 seconds. Am I doing something horribly wrong? Or is MCA not a deterministic global optimization algorithm, unlike PCA which is. If so, is there another implementation I should be looking at? I'm just trying to find a fast, descent dimensionality reduction technique for sparse categorical (binary) data.

Comment: Try to use skmca or Prince : https://github.com/MaxHalford/Prince

Comment: How is your data like? Does it have categorical or numerical data?

Comment: The data is numerical

Comment: If its numerical, you should be using PCA, MCA is more for categorical data [MCA](https://pypi.org/project/mca/). I think what is happening is that its assuming that your data is categorical and then it takes up time trying to convert it to numerical for dimension reduction. However dont take my word for it, im not 100% sure.

Comment: I don't think that's what's happening. Even if I don't run the `mca.dummy()` function which converts data to numerical categorical data (and convert it myself), it still doesn't complete within an hour. The actual MCA is what's taking forever and im not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the MCA package I was using. Use [Prince](https://github.com/MaxHalford/Prince#multiple-correspondence-analysis-mca), like @LazyCoder suggested. I'm not quite sure why it's so much faster, but that seemed to solve it.